# YouTrack Query: how to get issues from last 10 days?

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

I'd like to get `from -10 days to today` with YouTrack Query but official document seems not supported.

- doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html#relative-date-parameters

In case of Jira, it supports `(updatedDate <= now() AND updatedDate >= -10d)`

Is there any way to get the result correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could set range

from documentation:
(https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html#Date-and-Period-Values)
Date and Period Values
Several search attributes reference values that are stored as a date. You can search for dates as single values or use a range of values to define a period.

Specify dates in the format: YYYY-MM-DD or YYYY-MM or MM-DD. You also can specify a time in 24h format: HH:MM:SS or HH:MM. To specify both date and time, use the format: YYYY-MM-DD}}T{{HH:MM:SS. For example, the search query created: 2010-01-01T12:00 .. 2010-01-01T15:00 returns all issues that were created on 1 January 2010 between 12:00 and 15:00.

You can also use pre-defined relative parameters to search for date values. The values for these parameters are calculated relative to the current date according to the time zone of the current user. The actual value for each parameter is shown in the query assist panel.

example:
typo it in query textbox
issue updated: 2018-07-17 .. 2018-07-07

I hope it's helpful because of it easiest than write lambdas

Answer (score 11):

There is no "easy" way to do this. 
As said here : https://youtrack-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000239504-Find-issues-modified-during-last-X-days, the closest solution for you is to use real dates.

Edit:

You can use one of these queries:

`updated: {This week}` - all issues modified during this week (starting on Monday)

`updated: {Last week}` - all issues updated during last week

**`updated: 2017-05-01 .. 2017-05-12` - all issues updated from May, 1st until May, 12th**

**`updated: 2017-05-01 .. Today` - all issues updated from May 1 until today** This one should work for you, you just have to change the date programmatically.

Answer (score 7):

This is supported since version 2020-4.

https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/whatsnew/2020-4/#relative-date-parameters-in-search-queries-and-reports